# Longest Palindrome from a given String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

[PROBLEM STATEMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMDnX.png)

the problem statement is in the image to which link is given. Basically I have to print the longest palindrome in the String given to me in the problem statement.

My Approach: I have basically tried to solve the problem with use of ArrayList collection framework in Java. So I have extracted bits of the String periodically through the substring function and the have checked whether that bit is a palindrome or not by invoking another function, if yes then store in the ArrayList (called as list here). Then through selection sort algorithm, sort the bits of Strings in the ArrayList and then print the longest possible palindrome, but for some reason it just doesn't print the desired output.

Attaching the code below:

```
class Solution {

    public boolean isPalindrome(String check)
    {
        String sum = " ";
        for(int i=check.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
          sum = sum + check.charAt(i);
        }
        if(sum.equalsIgnoreCase(check)==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sum = " ";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++)
        {
          for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
          {
               sum = s.substring(i,j+1);
          
          if(isPalindrome(sum)==true)
          {
              list.add(sum);
              sum= " ";
          }
          else
          {
              sum=" ";
              continue;
          }
          }
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
        {
            int minIndex=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++)
            {
               if(list.get(j).length()<list.get(minIndex).length())
               {
                   minIndex=j;
               }
            }
            String temp = list.get(i);
            list.add(i, list.get(minIndex));
            list.add(minIndex, temp);
        }

        if(list.size()!=0)
        {

        
        String get = list.get(list.size()-1);
        return get;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code.

The first one is that you constantly initialize sum as

```
sum = " ";
```

This is not an empty String, but a String already containing a space. Because you keep adding this extra space at the beginning of your Strings all your comparisons via equalsIgnoreCase will fail. (Because you will for example compare " it" with "it")

Your second problem is the second nested loop, because you tell your loop to iterate over the length of the list, but then add 2 additional objects to the list with each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    // irrelevant code cut ....
    list.add(i, list.get(minIndex));
    list.add(minIndex, temp);
}
```

So the list will keep on growing and the loop will never reach the end of the List.

My guess is that you are trying to sort the list, but whatever your idea was it would be best to just start over and look up how lists are sorted.

The fixed version of your code:

```
class Solution {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(final String check) {
        String sum = "";
        for (int i = check.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum = sum + check.charAt(i);
        }
        if (sum.equalsIgnoreCase(check) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String longestPalindrome(final String s) {
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sum = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                sum = s.substring(i, j + 1);
                if (isPalindrome(sum) == true) {
                    list.add(sum);
                    sum = "";
                } else {
                    sum = "";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        
        // Sort Strings by length
        Collections.sort(list, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));

        if (list.size() != 0) {
            final String get = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            return get;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String palindrome = longestPalindrome("Polagerregale");
        System.out.println(palindrome);
    }
}
```

Running this code will give you the correcvt result of "lagerregal" as output.

Comment: thanks for the help.....much appreciated....looks like the problems that you pointed out were the only main problems in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. It uses a map (to try to make things more efficient). The other way — without using a map — is a little simpler, but it might  take longer to run, especially for large strings.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LongestPalindrome {
    private String input, output = "";
    private Map<Character, List<Integer>> map;

    public LongestPalindrome(String input) {
        this.input = input;
        populate();
        compute();
    }

    private void populate() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            Character c = input.charAt(i);
            if (!map.containsKey(c)) 
                map.put(c, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            map.get(c).add(i);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(String substring) {
        boolean palindrome = true;
        int len = substring.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
            if (substring.charAt(i) != substring.charAt(len-1-i)) {
                palindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return palindrome;
    }

    private void compute() {
        if (input.isEmpty()) { 
            return;
        }
        output = input.substring(0, 1);
        for (Character c : map.keySet()) {
            List<Integer> lst = map.get(c);
            int len = lst.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (int j = len-1; j > i; j--) {
                    int begin = lst.get(i);
                    int end = lst.get(j);
                    if (end - begin + 1 > output.length()) {
                        String substring = input.substring(begin, end + 1);
                        if (isPalindrome(substring)) {
                            output = substring;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return output;
    }

    public static void test(String testCase) {
        System.out.println("Test case: " + testCase);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LongestPalindrome result = new LongestPalindrome(testCase);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Longest palindrome: " + result);
        System.out.printf("Time taken: %d ms\n", time);
        System.out.println("====================");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("x");
        test("xx");
        test("xyyx");
        test("1xyyx2");
        test("abcdedcba");
        test("xx1abcdedcba1y");
        test("");
        test("  xyyx");
    }
}
```

I think that the map approach avoids a lot of unnecessary operations. Without a map, we could use a nested for loop, but the time complexity would be O(n^2).

In the code above, the populate() method is O(n), the isPalindrome method is O(n), and the compute() method is hopefully a lot faster than the O(n^2) approach, because it minimizes the number of operations.

There might be a more efficient algorithm for finding the longest palindrome in a given string. I tested the code above with several test cases and it seems to work fine.